# Is regex a costly operation? It seems atleast

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing

I was writing a regex pattern for a string. The string being a constant type/structure. What I mean is, it looks like(this format is not so important, have a look at the example next)-

```
[Data Code Format]: POP N/N/N (N: object): JSON object data
```

Here N represents a number or digit. and what's inside [ ] is a set of string block. But, this format is constant.

So, I wrote a regex-

```
\s*((?:\S+\s+){1}\S+)\s*(?:\((?:.*?)\))?:\s*(\S*)\s*(\w+)
```

Keeping this string example in mind-

```
%DATA-4-JSON: POP 0/1/0 (1: object): JSON object data
```

It works perfectly, but, what I see on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) is that there is a successful match. But, it has undergone 330 steps to achieve this.

Screenshot-

[image]

**My question is**, its taking 330 steps to achieve this(atleast in my mind I feel its pretty heavy), which I guess can be achieved using `if-else` and other comparisons with lesser steps right?

I mean, is regex string parsing so heavy? 330 steps for like 10000's of strings I need to parse is going to be heavy right?

Comment: Replace `.*?` with `[^)]*`. Also why did you put the `{1}`?

Comment: {1} is because I need (?:\S+\s+) to repeat exactly once. If there are spurious text's that come, I don't that to get parsed.

Comment: Anything gets matched only once by default.

Comment: "Costly" compared to what? Is $200 expensive?

Comment: _"{1} is because I need (?:\S+\s+) to repeat exactly once"_ Which it will by default.  Check the explanation on the right on regex101 for that quantifier: _"Exactly 1 time (**meaningless quantifier**)"_

Comment: Poorly written regex patterns are not only costly, they are dangerous. This one has too many consequent subpatterns that can match empty strings. Thus, backtracking falls into them and fails, and re-tries, and fails... That makes your pattern costly.

Comment: You can actually share links from regex101, no need to use screenshot.

Comment: @zerkms No, not $200 bucks, I guess I have clearly written in the question with that I am comparing to. Is it costlier w.r.t. a normal string operation, like using split, splice, etc., to separate tokens and get what is needed.

Comment: @bozzmob you sure have "which I guess can be achieved using if-else and other comparisons with lesser steps right?" --- now try to implement it and then we would at least be able to compare apples and oranges. At the moment you're comparing apples with nothing. It's not obvious how you compare the "step" from the regex101 site and a generic JS statement.

Comment: @ndn That doesn't give what I need actually. Have a look at my screenshot. I need those specific tokens. Your link just gives the whole string from POP to object.

Comment: @zerkms I am not sure. That's what I am asking help for. The whole operation for 10000+ strings is taking like few seconds to execute. I asked for help not -ve votes.

Comment: Yes, regex is expensive, so use it wisely.

Comment: Help with what? It takes few seconds. So?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer that's a harmful advice. They are not expensive by themselves. Nothing is expensive unless you set some explicit competitor and context.

Comment: There is no point in giving -ve votes when there is no clear explanation for anything. Also, not everyone is a pro here. Doubts are asked to seek more knowledge, not to get criticized.

Comment: Your question currently sounds like "Is $200 a high price?". Please answer that.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Thanks David.

Comment: @bozzmob David's comment is not correct. You just hear what you want to hear.

Comment: @bozzmob Write a function that does it without regex and compare the two. If it needs to be fast then trying out several solutions is often a good idea. Browsers have profiling tools (hit F12) that you can use to measure it.

Comment: @zerkms Yes, that is what I am asking. If say I ask a question - If a rest api takes like 5-6 seconds, is it more? For me, its YES its more. Imagine a person looking at a screen for like a total of 7 secs for nothing(REST + UI operation). So, what I basically asked is, is this more? and is there a better way?

Comment: @bozzmob ask your supervisor/customer if 5-6 seconds fits the required SLA. There is no universal answer for how long an arbitrary request must take. So, you're continuing asking if "Is $200 a high price?" here. "and is there a better way?" --- a better way for **what**? You haven't explained the original problem.

Comment: @zerkms I am looking for a single(or multiple) answer/s for an optimization. Anyway, thanks for your response.

Comment: Why do you avoid my question - "Is $200 a lot?". Just hold your breath and try to see what I mean. "for an optimization"--- for optimisation of **WHAT**? To help you optimise something you must explain the original task in details.

Comment: @zerkms I guess I did answer it. I am asking is there a better way than 7secs. What more of a comparison do you need?

Comment: **You need to explain the problem you're solving**. "is there a better way than 7secs" --- remove your code and the service will respond instantly. If all you care is the response time not the job that should be completed - it's the way to go. "I guess I did answer it" --- you did not. Is $200 a lot?

Comment: @bozzmob: Please try to understand what zerkms is trying to say here. If someone asks you *"is $1000 costly for a watch?"*, then *"yes"* is a wrong answer, *"no"* is a wrong answer too. The correct answer would be *"it depends"*. Anything else would be just opinionated.

Comment: Problem - "Over a period of time, a JSON file gets filled with events(string format I was talking about). These events are logs from several operations that happen in the server. So, there are like 100k+ events, out of which only 10k-ish are relevant or valuable. So, I need to parse these 10k events and display them as tasks to be solved) Problem here is, I should not use any DB for now. It should be a direct pull from JSON. Basically a real-time pull of data from JSON"

Comment: @Abhitalks See, What I am telling is with respect to a reference. If $1000 is costly for a plastic watch? YES! But for an Apple watch... Hmmm... No... Here its a reference to the "TYPE" of operation. Similarly, is 7 secs more for a DB query that only happens in the backend(not user facing), NO!! But, is 7secs more for a UI to load? YES! I am clearly talking about "with respect to" and a "reference"

Comment: I applied the provided regex to the provided string 10k times and my chrome could run it instantly. Why do you think it's the regex that is in charge for 7 seconds latency?

Comment: @zerkms I have given you my problem statement. Looking forward for some thoughts on the same.

Comment: I just have - that 10k iterations cannot take 7 seconds. It's something else that is slow. (which is another reason why trying to optimise what you think is slow is the wrong way to optimise anything). What you must do instead is to profile then deal with facts, not assumptions.

Comment: @zerkms Anyway, there are 2 optimizations which I have to look at - reading the JSON file and Parsing the strings. Well, it was quite a discussion! I am a science student, maybe I relate to things that are imaginary ;) Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you are using regexps, they can be costly if you use backtracking. When you use quantifiers with consequent patterns that may match one another (and in case the patterns between them may match empty strings (usually, declared with `*`, `{0,x}` or `?` quantifiers)), backtracking might play a bad trick on you.

What is bad about your regex?

A slight performance issue is caused by an unnecessary non-capturing group `(?:\S+\s+){1}`. It can be written as `\S+\s+` and it will already decrease the number of steps ([a bit, 302 steps](https://regex101.com/r/sZ5bX6/1)). However, the worst part is that `\S` matches the `:` delimiter. Thus, the **regex engine has to try a lot of possible routes to match the beginning** of your expected match. Replace that `\S+\s+\S` with `[^:\s]+\s+[^:\s]+`, and the [step amount will decrease to 159](https://regex101.com/r/sZ5bX6/2)!

Now, coming to `(?:\((?:.*?)\))?` - removing the unnecessary inner non-capturing group gives another slight improvement ([148 steps](https://regex101.com/r/sZ5bX6/3)), and replacing `.*?` with a negated character class gives another boost ([139 steps](https://regex101.com/r/sZ5bX6/4)).

I'd use this for now:

```
\s*([^:\s]+\s+[^:\s]+)\s*(?:\([^()]*\))?:\s*(\S*)\s*(\w+)
```

If the initial `\s*` was obligatory, it would be another enhancement, but you would have different matches.

Comment: +1 for clear explanation on "How to optimize" and "What is wrong"! That was exactly what I was looking for.