# How to slicing url?

Tags: python, slice

I want to slice my url from `https://exemple.com/key-system-1?hwid=07f8f20b7419f622&zone=Europe/Rome`
to `hwid=07f8f20b7419f622`.

I tried

```python
url = "https://exemple.com/key-system-1?hwid=07f8f20b7419f622&zone=Europe/Rome"
uirl = url[: url.find("hwid")]
print (uirl)
```

But the result is

```text
https://exemple.com/key-system-1?
```

Comment: Move the colon in the slice to the end -- `uirl = url[url.find("hwid"):]` and then `split` on `&` -- `uirl = url[url.find("hwid"):].split('&')[0]`. Another solution is to use any number of libraries meant to handle URL's and query params.

Comment: The 'correct' way to parse a URL is using the `urllib` library, with its `parse` module. [Documentation linked here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-parsing)

Answer (score 2):

Use a exisiting lib with which you can parse a whole url and get differnet componets easily. dont go for string slicing approach in this case.  you can achive this with `urllib`

with `urllib` you can do this as

```
>>> url = "https://exemple.com/key-system-1?hwid=07f8f20b7419f622&zone=Europe/Rome"
>>> import urllib
>>> query_parms = urllib.parse.urlparse(url).query
>>> query_parms
'hwid=07f8f20b7419f622&zone=Europe/Rome'
>>> query_parms_dict = urllib.parse.parse_qs(query_parms)
>>> query_parms_dict
{'hwid': ['07f8f20b7419f622'], 'zone': ['Europe/Rome']}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you used `:` wrong when you tried to slice the string

```
url = old_url[:index]
```

means that the new value of `url` is the part of `old_url` from 0 to `index`

and

```
url = old_url[index:]
```

means that the new value of `url` is the part of `old_url` from `index` to the end of  `old_url

in conclusion to get the result you are locking for you could use the following code

```
url = "https://exemple.com/key-system-1?hwid=07f8f20b7419f622&zone=Europe/Rome"
url_slice_1 = url[url.find("hwid"):]
url_slice_2 = url_slice_1[:url_slice_1.find("&")]
print (url_slice_2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex:

```
x = re.search("hwid=.*&", yourURL)
```

after that trim the last sign to get rid of the &

```
result = x[:-1]
```

Comment: Nope, for many reasons. Two of which 1) regex is overkill and expensive, 2) this approach is extremely fragile.

Comment: im pretty new to coding, why is regex overkill here?

Comment: Sure, good question. Regex is an exceedingly useful tool, and at the same time, it has it's place. [Your regex](https://regex101.com/r/8EAylS/1) isn't bad (because it's simple), but take 27 steps to process. Whereas [they can be very expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34675820/6340496), if not constructed optimally. In your case, it's overkill as parsing a URL with regex is discouraged as the `urllib.parse` module provides a *robust and mature* solution for this. Therefore, *in this case* regex is unnecessary, and fragile.

Comment: Required (albeit interesting) additional reading. [Now <you> have two problems.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/223634/362405)

Answer (score 0):

```
url = 'https://exemple.com/key-system-1?hwid=07f8f20b7419f622&zone=Europe/Rome'

#The actual start-idx is not the index of hwid= as the indx of hwid= is the index of the first letter of hwid= i.e 'h'
# So count the numbers of rest of the letters in hwid= and 1 to it to get the start_index( 4 + 1 = 5)

st = url.find('hwid=') + 5

end = url.find('&zone')
sliced_url = url[st:end]
print(sliced_url)  #Output: 07f8f20b7419f622
```